# Coding for Factorials in C++ using classes

Tags: c++

Received the following assignment in my C++ OOP class.

Convert the following procedural program, which calculates a Factorial, into a program that uses a class to calculate the factorial.

```
#include <iostream.h>

int factorial(int);

int main(void) {
    int number;
    cout << "Please enter a positive integer: ";
    cin >> number;
if (number < 0)
    cout << "That is not a positive integer.\n";
else
    cout << number << " factorial is: " << factorial(number) << endl;
}

int factorial(int number) {
    int temp;
    if(number <= 1) return 1;
    temp = number * factorial(number - 1);
    return temp;
}
```

Use the Following Driver Program.  A Driver program means that the int main() ... is already written for you. You only need to create the class and add it to the code.

HINT:  Look at the Name of the class used in the code below (factorialClass), and look at the method/function name used below (FactNum).. Your new class MUST use them...

```
int main(void) {

 factorialClass FactorialInstance;  //

 cout << "The factorial of 3 is: " << FactorialInstance.FactNum(3) << endl;

 cout << "The factorial of 5 is: " << FactorialInstance.FactNum(5) << endl;

 cout << "The factorial of 7 is: " << FactorialInstance.FactNum(7) << endl;

 system("pause");  // Mac user comment out this line

}
```

I've done OK on my own, but I'm getting a bunch of error messages and I'm not sure what I'm missing. I've found lots of other chunks of code online that create factorial programs easily, but I'm not sure how to integrate that with his preferred driver code. Here's what I've got so far below.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class factorialClass{
    int f, n; 
    public: 
    void factorialClass::FactorialInstance();
{
f=1;
cout<<"\nEnter a Number:";
cin>>n;
for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    f=f*i;
}
}

int main(void) {

 factorialClass FactorialInstance;  //

 FactorialInstance.FactNum();

 cout << "The factorial of 3 is: " << FactorialInstance.FactNum(3) << endl;

 cout << "The factorial of 5 is: " << FactorialInstance.FactNum(5) << endl;

 cout << "The factorial of 7 is: " << FactorialInstance.FactNum(7) << endl;

 system("pause");  // Mac user comment out this line
}
```

Comment: `#include <iostream.h>`  If you're given this in a C++ course, get your money back.  The proper header is `<iostream>`

Comment: oh yes this "professor" is literally the worst, but I'm required to take this class to transfer and it's the only version being taught at my school. His online class is sadly better than the version where you have to actually show up and hear him lecture, but his code is so incredibly shotty that it's nearly impossible to feel ready to do any actual coding in the real world.

Comment: Ditch the `factorialClass::` for functions in your class declaration.

Answer (score 2):

This is a silly assignment. A factorial function is not a proper member of an object,  but to complete the requirements of your main it would look something like:

```
struct factorialClass{
  int FactNum(int number = 1) {  // default argument helps with the first call
    if(number <= 1) return 1;
    return number * FactNum(number - 1);
}
```

Functions don't do input, they do arguments.

Answer (score 1):

create class `factorialClass` by

```
class factorialClass
{
};
```

Now add the function to compute factorial. `FactNum(int)`

```
class factorialClass
{
public:
     int FactNum(int x)
     {
        //code to compute factorial
        //return result
     }
};
```

Test with driver class.

Comment: Thank you. That cleared things up for me. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include<iostream>
        using namespace std;
    
    //create a class named factorial
    
        class factorial{
            private:
            int num,n=1;
            public:
    // create function getnum for getting the number you want factorial of.
            void getnum();
    // create function getfactorial and use any of your desired loop. 
            void getfactorial();
    //create function display for couting the value of the factorial.
            void display();
        };
    //you can access the function outside the class as well.
        void factorial::getnum()
        {
            cout<<"Enter the number you want to get factorial of";
            cin>>num;
        }
        void factorial::getfactorial()
        {
            for ( int i=num; i>0; --i){
                n=n*i; 
            }
        }
        void factorial::display()
        {
             cout<<n<<endl;
        }
        int main()
        {
            factorial obj;
//recall the functions here.
            obj.getnum();
            obj.getfactorial();
            obj.display();
        }
```

Comment: You should add some explanation(s) as to why you think this answer is a *significant* improvement over those posted some years earlier.